# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function with domain of an open disk $A \subset \mathbb R^2$. Suppose that its partial derivatives exists at $a\in A$ and that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous in $A$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$

I know that if I can prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous in $A$, then I'm done. However, from what given I can't see anything that can lead to that conclusion

Comment: Have a look at the *proof* of the result you are mentioning. Maybe this proof is flexible enough to allow you to show differentiability assuming only that one partial derivative is continuous.

Comment: @Etienne I looked at the proof and can't see any way to prove this using that proof.

Comment: So, look at the proof below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $a=(x_0,y_0)$, and set (for $u,v$ small enough)
$$\Delta(u,v)=f(x_0+u,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0)-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\, u+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\, v\right)$$
One has to show that $\Delta(u,v)=o(\Vert (u,v)\Vert)$ as $(u,v)\to (0,0)$, where $\Vert\;\;\Vert$ is any norm on $\mathbb R^2$.

The idea is to write $$f(x_0+u,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0+u,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0+v)+f(x_0,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0)\, .$$

Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists in $A$, one can find $c_{u,v}$ between $x_0$ and $x_0+u$ such that 
$$f(x_0+u,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0+v)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c_{u,v}\, y_0+v) \, u\, . $$
This gives
\begin{eqnarray}\Delta(u,v)&=&\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c_{u,v}, y_0+v)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right)u+ \\
& &\left(f(x_0,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\, v\right)
\end{eqnarray}
The first term in the right-hand side is $o(u)$ as $(u,v)\to (0,0)$ because $(c_{u,v},y_0+v)\to (x_0,y_0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous at $a=(x_0,y_0)$; and the second term is $o(v)$ by the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$. Altogether, this gives $\Delta(u,v)=o(\Vert (u,v)\Vert)$ , as required.

Comment: From my understanding , you let $(x,y)=(x_0+u,y_0+v)$? what is $o(u)$ and $o(v)$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Yes, $(x,y)=(x_0+u,y_0+v)$. The notation "$o(u)$" means "something negligible with respect to u". And likewise for $o(v)$.

Comment: I talked to my professor, and she said I need to somehow link this problem to the definition of differentiable function that is $f$ is differentiable on $D$ if for $(x_0,y_0)\in D$, $f(x,y)= f(x_0,y_0)+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)+r(x,y)$ and $lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)} \frac {r(x,y)}{\sqrt {(x-x_0)^2 +(y-y_0)^2}}=0$

Comment: Your professor is right, of course. The limit above says that $r(x,y)$ is $o(\Vert (x-x_0,y-y_0)\Vert)$ as $(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)$. You should see the link with my answer...

Comment: I wonder if you can go to the chat room with me now ?

Comment: I'd rather not chat. Are you in trouble with my answer?

Comment: yes, right after the line say that Since $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}$ exits in $A$ Did you missed $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$ or you just left it out intentionally? If so, how cna you do that?

Comment: At this point I do not need $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot$ I apply the mean-value formula to the 1-variable function $x\mapsto f(x, y_0+v)$ between $x=x_0$ and $x=x_0+u$.

Comment: ok, and from there, what did you o to have the equation $\triangle (u,v)$ after that, the oen that hev partial derivative respect to $y$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question

Comment: a) $f(x0+u,y0+v)−f(x0,y0+v)=∂f/∂x(cu,vy0+v)u.$

This gives

b) $Δ(u,v)=(∂f∂x(cu,v,y0+v)−∂f∂x(x0,y0))u+(f(x0,y0+v)−f(x0,y0)−∂f∂y(x0,y0)v)$ 

how do you got from a) to b)? Substitution some how?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the formula for $\Delta(u,v)$, you replace $f(x_0+u,y_0+v)-f(x_0,y_0+v)$ by what you have in (a).